# Integrating Access and Outlook with VBA for regular reporting

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm looking to put together some VBA code in access to send out a bunch of emails at once. These emails each have multiple attachments and multiple recipients.

I have one table in Access where the Primary Key is a list of "Email Report Names" each column contains an email address that this Email Report goes to.

In another table I also have the "Email Report Names" and each column is the filepath on the harddrive of a file to be attached to that email.

I also have two Queries that call on these tables and filter by the Email Report Name which is filled into the criteria field by a custom function.

I've got the outlook coding working fine to send emails from Access. But I'm totally clueless how to make it loop through the different "Email Report Names" then pull the relevent info out of those queries to fill in the recipient lists and attachment lists.

Sorry to not include any example code, but I'm really out to sea on this and don't even know where to start.

If there are any solutions that are pure VBA with no SQL that would be ideal. I don't know any SQL yet so I'd have a hard time modifying the code as neccessary even if I do get it initially working.

Thanks,

---

```
SELECT FilePaths.MailItem, FilePaths.FilePath1, 
       FilePaths.FilePath2, FilePaths.FilePath2, 
       FilePaths.FilePath4, FilePaths.FilePath5, 
       FilePaths.FilePath6, FilePaths.FilePath7,
       FilePaths.FilePath8, FilePaths.FilePath9, 
       FilePaths.FilePath10, FilePaths.FilePath11, 
       FilePaths.FilePath12, FilePaths.FilePath13, 
       FilePaths.FilePath14, FilePaths.FilePath15, 
       FilePaths.FilePath16 
FROM FilePaths 
WHERE (((FilePaths.MailItem)=EmailItemSelect()));
```

Comment: At the least, post the sql of the two queries "that call on these tables"

Comment: It is often a sign of a design fault when you have numbered field names (field1, field2 etc).

Comment: What does Email Report Names table look like?

Comment: There are two tables. The first column in both is MailItems which is the primary key in both. In one table each column after the first is FilePath1, FilePath2, etc. In the other table each column after the first is EmailAddress1, EmailAddress2, etc. I could reformat these any way that makes this easier. I set it up this way so that one variable could be put into the "EmailItemSelect()" function to have the two queries pull up the neccessary info.

Comment: That is quite confusing. Would it be correct to say you wish to send attachments FilePath1 to FilePath16 to EmailAddress1 to EmailAddress<unknownnumber>?

Comment: Yes. There won't always be the same number of files or recipients, but the number of files is always less than 16 and the number of recipeints is always less than 10. Believe me, I'm confused too.

Comment: Would a redesign be an option for you?

Comment: Totally. This is a new thing I'm creating for my personal use. I can set it up anyway that's easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to set up your tables is on these lines:

EmailAddresses

```
ID 
EmailAddress
OtherDetails
```

Filepaths

```
ID
MailItem
FilePath
```

EmailaddressFilepath

```
FilePathID
AddressID
```

I am not quite sue what mailitem is, so I left it in.

The table EmailaddressFilepath contains a match for which address is to receive which items.

EmailAddresses

```
ID     EmailAddress    OtherDetails
1      joe@example.com Joe Bloggs
```

Filepaths

```
ID    MailItem    FilePath
1     Help        z:\docs\help.doc
2     More help   z:\docs\morehelp.doc
```

EmailaddressFilepath

```
FilePathID    AddressID
   1              1
   2              1
```

You will then need some code

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db as Database

''Something like
sSQL="SELECT EmailAddress, Filepath " _
    & "FROM ( EmailaddressFilepath " _
    & "INNER JOIN EmailAddresses ON " _
    & "EmailaddressFilepath.AddressID = EmailAddresses.ID) " _
    & "INNER JOIN Filepaths ON EmailaddressFilepath.FilePathID = Filepaths.ID " _
    & "WHERE FilePathID=1"


Set rs = db.Openrecordset(sSQL)

'You now have a recordset with email addresses and attachments
'there would be other approaches, but this will do for now.

 Do While Not rs.EOF
     sEmail=rs!Email
     'set up outlook email

     Do While rs!Email=sEmail
     ''Attachment
         sAttach=rs!Filepath 
         rs.MoveNext
         If rs.Eof Then
            exit loop
         End if
     Loop
 Loop
```

Comment: How would I use this to create emails that go to multiple recipients with multiple attachments on each email?

Comment: That is the easy bit, just a minute.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just got this working. Is there a way for me to post the final working code for others to see on here?

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, just choose add an answer.

Comment: Just started to put this together and I realized with this method I'm going to need to manually enter around 10,000 different values in the EmailAddressFilePath table for this to work... Hmmm...

Comment: Okay, I'm lost. I don't know any SQL. Is there a way to do that without creating a separate query for every email I want to send.

Comment: Post some of your existing sample data and then I can suggest ways to deal with your data in particular, rather than standard approaches to this type of data.